# multi files with esp8266

Tags: lua, esp8266, esplorer

I am new to the ESP8266 and lua, is it possible to work with multiple files on the ESP8266 ? 
I have 2 files the first one called `foo.lua` 
and it contains this code :

```
function double(n)
  return n * 2
end
```

and the other file `new.lua` just call the first file as following:

```
require 'foo'
print(foo.double(5))
```

So can i use this technique with the esp8266 ?

I tried that but when I press save to esp button i get

[image]

and

[image]

and another popup messages

and these get printed on the console :

```
> file.remove("foo.lua");
> file.open("foo.lua","w+");
> w = file.writeline
> w([[function double(n)]]);
stdin:1: open a file first
> w([[  return n * 2]]);
stdin:1: open a file firstw([[end]]);
stdin:1: open a file firstw([[]]);
stdin:1: open a file firstw([[print (double(2))]]);
stdin:1: open a file firstfile.close();dofile("foo.lua");
cannot open foo.lua
```

even when i try to run the file using send to ESP button it works but it will not be saved.

Comment: Where is the code that contains `w = file.writeline`? Because that would appear to either be incorrect or `file.open` has failed somehow (and was not caught).

Comment: i dont have w = file.writeline in any code file.

Comment: That must come from somewhere. Presumably it is part of the tool you are using to do this. In any case the problem is either that assignment or (more likely I think) the `file.open` call is failing. I can't speculate on why it would be failing though. And without something doing something with its return status there isn't likely much you can do to figure out what might be failing. Asking someone familiar with the tool directly might be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way you can achieve that. But you can't just call like `foo.double(5)`.
I recommend you to try to put your function inside a class. Then you just have to compile it, with the command:

```
node.compile("foo.lua")
```

If you use the explorer, write it in the bottom right of the program, where you have a send button.

To create a class you should use a template, I recommend you to use this one:

```
function Class(members)
  local mt = {
     __metatable = members;
    __index     = members;
  }
  local function new(_, init)
    return setmetatable(init or {}, mt)
  end
  local function copy(obj, ...)
    local newobj = obj:new(unpack(arg))
    for n,v in pairs(obj) do newobj[n] = v end
    return newobj
  end
  members.new  = members.new  or new
  members.copy = members.copy or copy
  return mt
end
```

And in your foo.lua just include this:

```
require'Class'
```

If you want to use class variables write them here and then

```
local foo_mt = Class(foo)
```

After that you can add all the defs you want.
Don't forget to finish with `return foo;`